# setting up local web server on mac yosemite

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I have followed the steps [here](https://www.computersnyou.com/3376/setup-apache-php-mysql-macosx-10-10-yosemite/) to set up a local web server but it is not working. I double and triple checked each step so I know that each step was done properly.

By not working I mean that `http://localhost/~username/*.html` is not a valid web address.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am not even really sure what information would be helpful so if I need to post anything just leave it in a comment.

Comment: What do you mean "not a valid web address". You're going to have to give us more information than that. What happens when you go to `http://localhost/`? How familiar are you with linux? Is this vmware? Have you opened the ports necessary to access this content? Are you sure you're typing in the correct address (`localhost` may not work if the server is remote)?

Comment: could you specify the error you are getting in your browser ? is it a 404 missing page or a server not found error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Yosemite (as in the tutorial) or Mavericks? Have you replaced ~username with your actual Mac username? Have you tried http://127.0.0.1/~yourusername/* ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure what you're doing, you might be better off installing [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/). It installs everything for you, and keeps it separate from the built-in Apache, so OS upgrades won't break it.

Comment: Yosemite has everything I need preinstalled, I do not see the point in installing MAMP for this reason, also I am using this as a learning experience.